# Is it safe to ride with one missing chainring bolt?

Tags: safety, chainring

I have a double chainring on my road bike but one of my chainring bolts has broken so I'm left with only 4 out of the 5 I'm supposed to have. Is it safe to ride? (just until replacements arrive)

Comment: (And I'd bet that there are folks out there who've been riding for years with two missing bolts.)

Comment: If your cranks don't work you're walking, but any bike shop should have the bolts.  I limped 4 miles back to a bikeshop successfully with 2 missing out of a 5-spider but I wouldn't have ridden it out the next day if the shop had been closed.  (I additionally had to ride several miles over cobblestones to reach decent tarmac and was afraid that that would shake more stuff loose and my command of the local language was just not that good.)

Comment: My big question would be why did the bolt break and does whatever caused it to break mean that the others are in some way weakened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you don't take your bike on a long strenuous ride or torque the snot out of it, you should be OK. Make sure the remaining 4 are properly tightened. Normal commuting should be fine.